# Prove the Identity For Fringe Patterns

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Prove the two Identities for
$-1 < r < 1$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n\cos n\theta =\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n\sin{n\theta}=\frac{r \sin\theta }{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$$

Sorry could not figure out how to format equations

Comment: Please make sure I formatted the right-hand side of the identities correctly. You can ask for corrections by posting a comment here, or study [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Looks perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(re^{\theta i}\right)^n=\frac1{1-re^{i\theta }}\;,\;\;\text{as long as}\;\;|r|<1$$

But

$$\frac1{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{|1-re^{i\theta}|^2}$$

and now just take the real and the imaginary parts...and remember, of course, that a complex sequence converges iff its real and imaginary parts converge each (and what's the relation of this with series convergence?)

**Added on request:** By definition, $\;e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\;,\;\;\theta\in\Bbb R\;$  . Sometimes, in particular at high school level, this is denoted by  cis$\,\theta\;$ .

Now, it's an easy exercise, using the polar form for complex numbers, to show that if $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ , then

$$z^{-1}=\overline z\iff |z|=1\iff z=e^{i\theta}$$

and from here, doing the usual and multiplying a complex fraction by the denominator's conjugate in the form of $\;1\;$, we get:

$$\frac1{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac1{1-re^{i\theta}}\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{1-re^{-i\theta}}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{|1-re^{i\theta}|^2}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{(1-r\cos\theta)^2+r^2\sin\theta^2}=$$

$$=\frac{1-r\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$$

because $\;\forall\,z\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;z\overline z=|z|^2=\text{Re}\,(z)^2+\text{Im}\,(z)^2\;$

Finally, if we have an infinite geometric series (real or complex) $\;a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,...,ar^n,...\;$ , with $\;|r|<1\;$ , then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n=\frac1{1-r}$$

since

$$\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k=a\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;r^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;\;\text{for}\;\;|r|<1$$

I'm assuming the OP knows the basics of complex numbers, e.g. de Moivre's formula:

$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$

which becomes pretty trivial if we use the exponential form $\;\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^n=e^{in\theta}\;$

Hope this helps. Any other doubt write back.

Comment: Where is the e^(itheta) coming into play? are we assuming it to be equal to cos(theta)+isin(theta)

Comment: and I am unaware of what the relation with series convergence is, any further explanation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\exp(i x) = \cos(x ) + i \sin(x).$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:Mathematical induction. For:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n\cos n\theta =\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}
$$
Let us consider:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n+1}\cos (n+1)\theta
$$
which is rewritten
$$
r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n}\left[\cos n\theta \cos \theta-\sin n\theta \sin \theta \right]
$$
$$
=r\cos \theta\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n}\cos n\theta - r \sin \theta \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n \sin n\theta \ \ \ (1)
$$
By hypothesis, we know that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n\cos n\theta =\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2} \ \ \ (2)
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n\sin{n\theta}=\frac{r \sin\theta }{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2} \ \ \ (3)
$$
Finally we substitute the equations (2) and (3) in (1). Finally, to prove the formula, simply replace the equations (2) and (3) in (1). Same procedure to demonstrate the equation (3).

Comment: What is this substitution proving in the end? other than an unfriendly fraction (r cos(theta)-r^2)/(r^2-2 r cos(theta)+1)